# How to externalize protobuf files in JVM ecosystem?

Tags: scala, grpc, lagom, akka-grpc

I stumbled upon this [Akka grpc tutorial](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/buildtools/sbt.html#loading-proto-files-from-artifacts) which suggests that we can create a jar from a project that has `.proto` file under `src/main/proto` and add it as a dependency in client and server projects to build their respective stubs.

```
libraryDependencies += "com.example" %% "my-grpc-service" % "1.0.0" % "protobuf-src"
```

But this doesn't seem to work!! Are there any example projects that demonstrates how this would work in action? How can we externalize protobuf sources and use the same in a jvm based project?

Comment: Are you adding the akka-grpc plugin to your build?

Comment: Enabled it both for client and server like so: `enablePlugins(AkkaGrpcPlugin)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to externalise protobuf files properly as per suggestion from [akka-grpc docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-grpc/current/buildtools/sbt.html#loading-proto-files-from-artifacts).

The problem was that I was not adding `sbt-akka-grpc` plugin required by sbt to recognise `.proto` files and include them in the packaged jar. Without this plugin there won't be any `.proto` file made available in the packaged jar.

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.akka.grpc" % "sbt-akka-grpc" % "1.1.0")
```

Make sure to add `organization` settings in your `build.sbt` to prepare jar correctly.

```
organization := "com.iamsmkr"
```

Also, if you wish to cross-compile this jar to multiple versions add following entries in your `build.sbt`:

```
scalaVersion := "2.13.3"
crossScalaVersions := Seq(scalaVersion.value, "2.12.14")
```

and then to publish:

```
$ sbt +publishLocal
```

With appropriate jars published you can now add them as dependencies in your client and server projects like so:

```
libraryDependencies += 
"com.iamsmkr" %% "prime-protobuf" % protobufSourceVersion % "protobuf-src"
```

You can check out [this project](https://github.com/iamsmkr/prime-grpc-scala-akka/tree/main/prime-protobuf) I am working on to see this in action.

##### Alternate Way

An alternate way I figured is that you can keep your `.proto` files in a `root` directory and then refer them in client and server `build.sbt` like so:

```
PB.protoSources.in(Compile) := Seq(sourceDirectory.value / ".." / ".." / "proto")
```

Checkout [this project](https://github.com/jospint/dixa-fibonacci) to see it in action.